# How to extend Django's user model

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I'm aware that there is a way to extend the user model in Django along with its authentication app. Is there a way to use an email as the username, and also create a user ID as the primary key?

Comment: This is actually documented in [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) or [Substituting a custom User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) and the trade offs between those choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Crosby already stated, you should write your model like this with a little something extra:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, ...)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Overriding the email field and making it a unique field would save you the stress of coding in view or someplace else to not allow duplicate emails.

Comment: Would this extend the existing User model?

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set `USERNAME_FIELD` to email.

By default, you can already use `pk` (or `id`) field as a user ID. If you need something specific, create a field with `primary_key=True`.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    your_own_identifier = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, ...)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Comment: I've tried it now and It works just as you said, thanks!